# creating permanent alias by editing .bashrc file

Tags: bashrc

I edited .bashrc file using vim. and then source it by command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc"
```

It show something like

```
/home/usr/.bashrc:16: command not found: shopt
/home/usr/.bashrc:24: command not found: shopt
/home/usr/.bashrc:108: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:35: parse error near `]]'
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

then I type adt (the alias) it worked.
,but when i closed the terminal & opened again it did not worked.
showed 
zsh: command not found: adt**
what should I do to fix it?

Comment: looks like you have errors in the .bashrc file .. can you open it and copy the text and edit your question pasting what your .bashrc file looks like .. seems you have errors on lines 16,24 and 108 and maybe other errors

Comment: Are you sourcing this in bash? What does `echo $0 $BASH_VERSION` report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors message suggests that you aren't using Bash but Zsh as your shell. Use the file `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Can I add alias in zsh file? or can I change bash as shell.

Comment: Yes, you can add aliases in ´~/.zshrc`. Or you can switch your shell using the `chsh` command.